# Login form in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, authentication

I am using Mysql netbeans . I have created a db table "userdetails_summertrainingproject" . In the login form I have two fileds to fill one is "UUId_JTextField" and other is "Password1_JPasswordField". I want to compare that the password value entered by the user is same as that in db for the particular UUId entered by the user. UUid is unique.

```
try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","");
                    String query = "SELECT password FROM userdetails_summertrainingproject WHERE UUId=?;";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1,UUId_JTextField.getText());
                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    char[] password1 = Password1_JPasswordField.getPassword();
                    String pass1 = new String(password1);
                    if(rs.getString(query)==pass1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in successfully");
                    }
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception in Login:"+e.getMessage());
            }
```

Above is the code I am using.
The Exception is:

> Exception in Login:Column 'SELECT password FROM userdetails_summertrainingproject WHERE UUId=?;' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you missed `rs.next()`

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mysql", "root", "");
        String query = "SELECT password FROM userdetails_summertrainingproject WHERE UUId=?;";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, UUId_JTextField.getText());
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        char[] password1 = Password1_JPasswordField.getPassword();
        String pass1 = Arrays.toString(password1);
        rs.next();
        if (rs.getString("password").equals(pass1)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in successfully");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think it is batter to use another method for get connection string. otherwise you have to write bellow code again and again.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mysql", "root", "");
```

**EDIT:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "");
        String query = "SELECT UUId FROM userdetails_summertrainingproject;";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        String UUId = rs.getString("UUId");
        System.out.println("UUId " + UUId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Create a class and add this code. then check this code is working or not. 
please make sure port, database name, user and password is correct.

If this is give `com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`. most probably your port is incorrect.

[image]

I am use these two libraries.

Comment: Still the same error : Exception in Login:Column 'SELECT password FROM userdetails_summertrainingproject WHERE UUId=?;' not found.

Comment: Please check this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j71Nm66sBe_bLAqKC5UR5SOgY5HAQjYNwC06xQn38GQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: when I run this code in my machine it is working. can you put complete Stack Trace error message. Find what is the line you got error and then try to find why it come from that line.

Comment: when you run this code is that part of code also worked where is popup Loggied in successfully  ?.   Here is the total exception list which is appearing while im trying to use the login code(second part of code)  exception link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x6aISapr9sRv7hYsptCP1cK4pLqstnbbf0NxJ2Y7Na8/edit?usp=sharing       Please help

Comment: I am only check your code `if` block contain part. it work correctly.  
summertrainingproject.SummerTrainingProject$3.actionPerformed(SummerTrainingProject.java:322)
what is the 322 line. That is the line you should check.

Comment: please make sure your code is pointing correct database table. and is there have userdetails_summertrainingproject  table.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19_zKJ6UGUhKUnGHvVh1ZIZ4CqVk4RnRxF2jIJ3qmzHw/edit?usp=sharing      <- Exception

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","");
      String query="SELECT password FROM tryingtable WHERE name=?;";
      PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
      prepstmt.setString(1,jtf.getText());
      ResultSet rs=prepstmt.executeQuery();
      rs.next();
      String result=rs.getString("password");;
      char[] pass = jpf.getPassword();
      String password1= new String(pass);
      if(result.equals(password1))
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "go!!");
       else
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no!!");

    }

      catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
      e.getStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: @SupunKavinda Thanks for your support. It really helped me .

Answer (score 0):

> > when you want to compare password field to textfield use

```
char[] pass_char = passwordField.getPassword();
String pass_string = new String(pass_char);
```

Above code will give you your password field value in string form, then

```
if(pass_string.equals(textfield))
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Password match");
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Password did not match");
```